# Setting environmental variables for apache user www-data

Tags: environment-variables, apache-http-server

I want to set the environmental variable `GNUPGHOME=/path/to/home` for the apache user `www-data`. I tried setting `GNUPGHOME` inside `/etc/profile` with

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 33 ]; then
    export GNUPGHOME="/path/to/home"
fi
```

Here 33 is the user id of the user `www-data`. However, even after a fresh restart when I `su www-data` and run `echo $GNUPGHOME` I see that the variable is not set.

How can I make it so the user `www-data`'s `GNUPGHOME` variable is set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file called`/etc/apache2/envvars` to which I added `export GNUPGHOME="/path/to/home"` which does what I wanted.

Comment: You can also use `SetEnv` (assuming you have `mod_env` enabled) if you wanted to set an environment variable only for a given site configuration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you want to set the environment variable for the actual Apache user, and not for use within Apache itself? Environment variables in Apache are usually implemented via a set of modules, with mod_env and friends - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

What exactly is your use case? Is there a script/cron that you need to run as the www-data user perhaps?

Comment: The use case is that I want to do some server side encryption using gpg, but don't want to store my secret keys in `/var/www/.gnupg`, so I want to change `GNUPGHOME` to a more suitable location for the apache user.